# In a $12$ sided regular convex polygon, all the diagonals are joined

Tags: geometry

In a $12$ sided regular convex polygon, all the diagonals are joined.How can I find the number of concurrent diagonals?
I can find the number of intersections..

Comment: What is a concurrent diagonal?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel not parallel

Comment: The diagonals are $12(12-3)/2=54$. For each side there are $4$ parallel diagonals which means that $4\times 12/2=24$ are parallel. So the concurrent should be $30$. Did I understand well the problem?